# “Hair” to is “hairy” as “key” is to what word?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

There is a noun *hair*, so person who has a lot of *hair* is *hairy*. So how about *key*; is there any word that means that person has *keys*. In programming terms, a container has keys for every value, like in a map.

---

So I need this for naming a class that is some combination of map and graph, because data is stored in a graph instead of in a tree, but every item can be accessed using a unique key.

Comment: Pick whatever you want- it's a class name not a sentence in English. If the class is a container for keys, call it a 'keyholder'.

Comment: Or perhaps a 'keyring'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing class names for a program is specifically off-topic according to the ELU Help Center.

Comment: "Keyed" is the word.  A scalp is "hairy" and a lock is "keyed".  (And if you simply look at the dozens of examples you will see that "keyed" is used regularly in software descriptions.)

Comment: The obvious answer is _keyy_, but that works better in speech than in writing.

Comment: So what you really want is the accepted practice of the name for a data structure that holds many keys. That is commonly called a map of dictionary or hash. You would get better results over at programmers.SE or SE.SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something that is characterized by keys is *keyed.*  There are precedents for using this word in class names, for example, the .NET [KeyedCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have been expecting some _fancy_ word, but it looks like simple option is the best.

Comment: @ST3 Well, it's simple, but it's certainly uncommon. So, I suppose that could lend it an air of fanciness.

Answer (score 3):

"Hair" is to "hairy" as "key" is to [key-laden](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wPuzML_Al78C&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=%22a+key-laden%22&source=bl&ots=LfInUENcho&sig=K1JMvapfZAAvXmJKTm-r2ncJOLc&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAWoVChMI8JXAxd-eyAIVRFwaCh15MQVc#v=onepage&q=%22a%20key-laden%22&f=false)

"*Success!" She said, pulling out a **key-laden** chain, selecting one and opening a door with it.* (Hope's War by Marsha Forchuk Skrypuch)